# Laravel Query where All

Tags: php, laravel

I wondered how to make a Where All clause with Laravel
I'm trying to check if the episodes that a user saw are all the episodes of the series.

I'm using the WhereIn clause but i returns the results if i saw one episode of the serie.

$alleps get all the episodes of the serie
$seriessaw get all the episodes a user saw

Thank you for your answers !

```
    $alleps = DB::table('episodes')
        ->select('episodes.id as ep_id')
        ->join('seasonsepisodes', 'episodes.id', '=', 'seasonsepisodes.episode_id')
        ->join('seriesseasons', 'seasonsepisodes.season_id', '=', 'seriesseasons.season_id')
        ->where('seriesseasons.series_id', '=', $id);

    $seriesSaw = DB::table('usersepisodes')
    ->select('usersepisodes.episode_id as ep_id')
    ->where('usersepisodes.user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)
    ->whereIn('usersepisodes.episode_id', $alleps)
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would need to set a `having` clause which would force records to only return if there's the same amount of records as there are amount of episodes.

```
$seriesSaw = DB::table('usersepisodes')
    ->select('usersepisodes.episode_id as ep_id')
    ->where('usersepisodes.user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)
    ->whereIn('usersepisodes.episode_id', $alleps)
    ->having(\DB::raw('count(*)'), count($alleps))
    ->get();
```

You should note however that this would likely break if there's any possibility of having duplicates in the `userepisodes` table.

Comment: The count don't get the good count value... but i found a solution : I take $alleps->count and $seriesSaw->count in two vars and i compare the result

Answer (score 0):

When you use `WhereIn`, you have to pass an array as the second parameter.

```
$alleps = DB::table('episodes')
        ->select('episodes.id as ep_id')
        ->join('seasonsepisodes', 'episodes.id', '=', 'seasonsepisodes.episode_id')
        ->join('seriesseasons', 'seasonsepisodes.season_id', '=', 'seriesseasons.season_id')
        ->where('seriesseasons.series_id', '=', $id)->get()->toArray();

    $seriesSaw = DB::table('usersepisodes')
    ->select('usersepisodes.episode_id as ep_id')
    ->where('usersepisodes.user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)
    ->whereIn('usersepisodes.episode_id', $alleps)
    ->get();
```

Comment: $alleps is already an array, the query is working if I have seen a episode of the serie